# How to change ASP MVC3 completed method for async controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, async-await

Currently I must have the same completed methods for all async methods. For instance:

```
public JsonResult <MethodName>Completed(object result)
{
    return Json(result);
}
```

How do I set other Async methods to use only one Completed method, let's say `public JsonResult CompletedMethod(object result)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do that. This is because ASP.NET MVC follows the convention over configuration principle.

That is why you'll have to create all Completed methods for your async actions.

You can simplify you code by encapsulating the logic that needs to be performed in the all Complete methods into a private method and returning it.

```
private JsonResult CompletedLogic(object param)
{ ... }

public JsonResult FooCompleted(object result)
{return CompletedLogic(result);}

public JsonResult BooCompleted(object result)
{return CompletedLogic(result);}
```